# Calculate average between 2 timer values

Tags: c#, java, puzzle

I wrote a function which does this functionality and I am not satisfied with the performance & implementation. I wanted to see if someone can help me implement this nifty functionality in an efficient way.

The function should return a string which is the average time between 2 timer values passed. 2 timer values are both strings of the format `"MM:SS:HS"` for example if values `"02:02:20"` and `"04:04:40"` are passed to the function it should output the average time between those values and return it as a string in the same format `"03.03.30"`.

I wanted to implement it in C#, Java is fine too.

Look forward to your solutions. Thanks for reading!

Comment: Please show us what you've got so far.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Use [`TimeSpan.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.parse.aspx) to parse the two values
- Add them together
- Take the number of ticks of the sum ([`TimeSpan.Ticks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.ticks.aspx)) and divide it by two to get the average (as you can't divide a `TimeSpan` directly)
- Use `TimeSpan.FromTicks` to convert back to a `TimeSpan`
- Call `ToString` to convert back from a `TimeSpan` to a string.

(I'm not sure why the other answers are suggesting subtraction, when a mean value is usually gained by *adding* values and then dividing...)

Personally I'd probably split this into two methods, one of which just did the averaging part, and the other of which did the text conversions:

```
public static TimeSpan Average(TimeSpan first, TimeSpan second)
{
    return TimeSpan.FromTicks((first + second).Ticks / 2);
}

public static string Average(string first, string second)
{
    TimeSpan firstSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(first);
    TimeSpan secondSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(second);
    return Average(firstSpan, secondSpan).ToString();
}
```

You may need to mess around a bit to get the exact text format you want - there are more options in .NET 4 than previously, using `ToString` with a format string etc.

Comment: Exactly! Sum and not substraction.

Answer (score 1):

Jon Skeet is right.  Here is the function to get the average of two TimeSpans

```
public TimeSpan TimeSpanAverage(TimeSpan earlier, TimeSpan later) {

    return (new TimeSpan((earlier.Ticks + later.Ticks) / 2));   

}
```

**Old Answer:**

Have you tried using [TimeSpan.Subtract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.subtract.aspx)?

You may use it like this

```
TimeSpan time1 = new TimeSpan(2, 2, 2);
TimeSpan time2 = new TimeSpan(4, 4, 4);

time1.Subtract(time2)
```

Subtract returns another TimeSpan

Comment: that won't give him the average. he'd have to divide as well

Answer (score 1):

In C#, use the DateTime/TimeSpan class. Take the Ticks property of both, add one to the other, divide by 2, and voila!

Answer (score 0):

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(04,04,04);
TimeSpan t2 = new TimeSpan(02,02,02);
Console.WriteLine(ts.Subtract(t2));
```

The TimeSpan has a Subtract method that will work this out for you.

Comment: how's he going to divide that by 2 to get the average?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution, by me, is to use Ticks property of DateTime class. In your case if your range is made of 2 DateTime values, just add  Ticks of both of them and devide it by  2. After construct new DateTime object by using ctor that accepts ticks as a parameter. This will be the average.